# Como inserir checkbox dinamicamente a partir de código Python/Flask?

Tags: python, checkbox, flask

Estou tentando criar um script em Flask e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

tenho no meu código um for que varre os sub-diretórios de um diretório raíz:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(destination):
    for name in dirs:
        ...
```

preciso colocar uma lista de checkbox no meu layout html com os nomes dos sub-diretórios respectivamente encontrados

Exemplo: o meu for encontrou 4 sub-diretórios (dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4). Portanto, no meu layout terá 4 checkbox (dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4).

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
import os # os.walk()

app = Flask("checkboxes") # from flask

def checkboxes(directory):
    all_names = ""
    template = "{}: <input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"{}\"/><br>\n"

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in dirs:
            all_names += template.format(name) # name vai para {0}.
    return all_names

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return checkboxes(".") # retorna all_names para a página.

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

O Jeito mais fácil é fazer isso diretamente no Jinja2

```
{% for d in dirs %}
    <input id="{{d}}" name="{{d}}" type="checkbox">
{% endfor %}
```